Can I use StateT/MaybeT/forever to eliminate explicit recursion from this IO action?
I have a program like this,
start :: [Q] -> R -> IO R
start qs = fix $ \recurse r -> do
  q <- select qs
  (r', exit) <- askQ q r
  (if exit
    then return
    else recurse) r'

that takes a list of Questions, a Report, and returns a new Report, in the IO monad because select needs it to pick a question at random (and also because askQ will wait for user keyboard input); however, the user did not choose to exit while executing askQ, start will recursively call itself. (fix $ \recurse is the trick to write a recursive lambda.)
The above code smells a lot like a few things:

the State monad, or, more appropriately, the StateT monad transformer, because R is evolving during start's recursion;
the forever applicative combinator, because start is recursive and could potentially run forever, if the user wants it to (i.e. if they never ask to exit);
the MaybeT monad transformer, because Maybe implements MonadPlus that should be able to short-circuit forever, based on what I read just before forever's implementation.

But can't really tell if any or more of those abstractions can be used to write the above code in a more idiomatic way, most importantly avoiding the explicit recursion.

This is just some experiment I've done in GHCi to gather a better understanding of the accepted answer.
Here's some utils for the following,
type M = MaybeT (StateT [String] IO) Int)
printAndRet rs@(r, s) = putStrLn ("result: " ++ show r ++ ", state: " ++ show s)
                        >> return rs

Here's 4 computations happening in the MaybeT-StateT-composed monad defined there,
c1 = ((MaybeT $ StateT $ \s -> printAndRet (Just 1, "again":s) ) :: M
c2 = ((MaybeT $ StateT $ \s -> printAndRet (Just 2, "once more":s) ) :: M
c3 = ((MaybeT $ StateT $ \s -> printAndRet (Nothing, "a final time":s) ) :: M
c4 = ((MaybeT $ StateT $ \s -> printAndRet (Just 10, "and never again":s) ) :: M

and here's what happens when we chain them together with >> and run the resulting action:
flip runStateT ["some initial state"] $ runMaybeT $ (c1 >> c2 >> c3 >> c4)
result: Just 1, state: ["again","some initial state"]
result: Just 2, state: ["once more","again","some initial state"]
result: Nothing, state: ["a final time","once more","again","some initial state"]
(Nothing,["a final time","once more","again","some initial state"])


In my eye, recursion (explicit or via fix) seems to be the form which is easier to understand to describe this task. It's very natural to see at the end "if condition, repeat". forever looks worse since the loop is not actually infinite. The other abstractions you mention do not seem to be able to encode the recursion. The best I can see would be using ContT, callCC and forever but ... I can't see why one would actually prefer that.

@chi, it's not that I think the original code for start is unclear in itself. I just think that it is clearly holding a state that changes during the recursion, and that's definitely not "documented" by the type, nor by the body. That's to say the 1st bullet point came first to my mind. As regards the other two, maybe leveraging those to shove a MaybeT in is a bit overkill, but worth learning, from my perspective. I hope that will give me a better and better understanding of Haskell.

@chi, and, by the way, it seems to me that forever is meant to mean "forever" just as much as return means "the return of procedural languages". Sometime it means that, for which name was chosen (e.g. return), but it's not meant to always mean that. Reason for my question is that I want to become comfortable in telling the difference of a given function depending on the monad it's running in. That's it.

Well, the result would be something like:
type M = MaybeT (StateT R IO)

start :: [Q] -> M ()
start qs = forever (select qs >>= askQ)

This presumes that select and askQ will be rewritten to run in the M monad instead of IO:
select :: [Q] -> M Q
askQ :: Q -> M ()

The result is very...  succinct.
A standalone example, for posterity...
import Data.Coerce
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import System.Random

newtype Q = Q String deriving (Show)
newtype R = R [String] deriving (Show)

type M = MaybeT (StateT R IO)

runM :: M a -> IO (Maybe a, R)
runM = flip runStateT (R []) . runMaybeT

select :: [Q] -> M Q
select qs = (qs !!) <$> randomRIO (0, length qs - 1)

askQ :: Q -> M ()
askQ (Q q) = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn q
  r <- liftIO getLine
  if r == "exit" then mzero
    else modify (coerce (r:))

start :: [Q] -> M ()
start qs = forever (select qs >>= askQ)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runM $ start [ Q "Is this idiomatic?"
                         , Q "Seriously, what's wrong with recursion?"
                         ]
  print result

It seems to work:
λ> main
Seriously, what's wrong with recursion?
nothing
Is this idiomatic?
yes
Is this idiomatic?
exit
(Nothing,R ["yes","nothing"])


This answer is so dense knowledge! And food for thoughts :)

You might be interested in my new question..

Because I've been playing around with recursion schemes lately, I thought I'd take a shot at a monadic hylomorphism
import Data.Functor.Foldable.Exotic
import Data.Functor.Base (NonEmptyF(..))

start qs = hyloM alg coalg where
  -- Build up a non-empty list ending with the final report.
  coalg r = do q <- select qs
               (r', exit) <- askQ q r
               return $ NonEmptyF r' (if exit then Nothing else Just r')

  -- Wade through the "other" reports to get to the last one.
  alg (NonEmptyF _ (Just x)) = return x
  alg (NonEmptyF r Nothing) = return r

There's almost certainly room for improvement here. (Off the top of my head, I'm fairly certain the list of bad reports isn't "fused" away.)

Looks like Either  can be used in place of NonEmptyF, with Left r' ~= NonEmpty r' Nothing and Right r' ~= NonEmpty r' (Just r').
